# tf.unique without repeating indices

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, unique, tensor

My input is a tensor of for example `[8,8,8,2,2,3,1,1,8,8]`. My output should be a tensor that references to each segment of this tensor which would look like this: `[0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,4,4]`. I have to compute that in tensorflow.

`tf.unique([8,8,8,2,2,3,1,1,8,8])` computes a tensor `[0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,0,0]` which has 0 instead of 4 at the end.

Does anyone know a way how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The operation that you want to do does not really have much to do with `tf.unique`. One way to achieve that result is this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def identify_blocks(a):
    neq = tf.not_equal(a[1:], a[:-1])
    c = tf.cumsum(tf.dtypes.cast(neq, tf.int32))
    return tf.concat([[0], c], axis=0)

a = tf.constant([8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 8])
b = identify_blocks(a)
print(b.numpy())
# [0 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 4 4]
```